# Parse Cloud Code: Retrieve Image Data For iOS App

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uiimage, nsdata, parse-cloud-code

I'm writing an iOS app with a Parse backend, and amongst other things it will list blog entries.

Each blog entry has an associated image, but I don't want to fetch the image object for each entry and then have to fetch the image file for each of those. So I wrote a cloud function that would combine the two steps and return the raw image data with a single request.

Here's the cloud code:

```
var imageFile = image.get("photoFile");
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: imageFile.url()
}).then(function(dataResponse){
  response.success(dataResponse.buffer);
});
```

When I do this, I get back an array of integers, and I don't know where to go from here to get a UIImage. Here's the iOS code I have so far:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground(latestImageCloudFunctionName, withParameters: parameters) { (imageData, error) -> Void in
    if let data = imageData {
        //imageData is of the type [Int]
    }
}
```

Is the image base64 encoded here? How do I get an NSData object from this that will create a UIImage?

Comment: Show the part where you are creating the UIImage from the in iOS.

Comment: I apologise, I was inaccurate with my question. It wasn't that I was getting a nil UIImage, I was getting a result from the cloud function that I didn't know what to do with. I've edited the question to reflect that, the result is an array of integers, and I'm not sure how to go from this to a UIImage.